# Get the last occurrence of an element

Tags: javascript

`getElementById(id)` returns the element with the matching ID attribute. How can I get the last occurrence of this element, as opposed to the first?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<button onclick="getLast()">Click me</button>

<div id="username">Lisa</div>
<div id="username">Chris</div>

<script>
function getLast() {
    alert(document.getElementById("username").innerHTML);
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

id is always unique. No two DOM elements can have the same id. In your case use the `class` attribute. Use `getElementsByClassName` which will return a collection. Get its length and use that value to get the last element.

```js
function getLast() {
  var getLastElemIndex = document.getElementsByClassName("username").length - 1;
  console.log(getLastElemIndex)
  alert(document.getElementsByClassName("username")[getLastElemIndex].innerHTML);
}
```

```html
<div class="username">Lisa</div>
<div class="username">Chris</div>
<button onclick="getLast()">Click me</button>
```

Answer (score 3):

`id` should be unique. But we don't have control on how people write their code and I also meet this case sometimes: "I need to parse the page and they are using same id"

You can treat `id` as an attribute and use `querySelectorAll`:

```html
<button onclick="getLast()">Click me</button>
<div id="username">Lisa</div>
<div id="username">Chris</div>
<script>
function getLast() {
    tags = document.querySelectorAll('[id="username"]');
    alert(tags[tags.length - 1].innerHTML);
}
</script>
```

And the best practice should be using `class`.

Comment: tags[tags.length - 1] is the better answer

Answer (score 1):

The `id` of a HTML element is meant to be unique. You should specify the `class` instead:

```
<div class="username">Lisa</div>
<div class="username">Chris</div>
```

Then use [Document.getElementsByClassName()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) to get all elements of that `class`:

```
var usernames = document.getElementsByClassName("username");
```

Alternatively, you can use [Document.querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll):

```
var usernames = document.querySelectorAll(".username");
```

And then you can get the last one:

```
var lastUsername = usernames[usernames.length - 1];
```

Answer (score 1):

Even you can do it by tag name `div`, as @brk said id must be unique.

```js
function getLast(){
  var divs = document.querySelectorAll("div");
  console.log(divs[divs.length - 1].textContent);
}
getLast();
```

```html
<button onclick="getLast()">Click me</button>
<div>Lisa</div>
<div>Chris</div>
```